# Программный запуск приложения

Tags: c++, winapi

Пишу на c++ нечто вроде текстового помощника, вводишь ему "открой что-то.exe", и он запускает это приложение. Использую функцию ShellExecute(). Допустим, должна открываться игра sekiro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ShellExecute(0, "open", "G:\\Games\\Sekiro Shadows Die Twice\\sekiro.exe", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);


    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так с любыми exe. файлами. Документы и папки открываются нормально.

Если запускать игру "вручную", то все прекрасно работает.

Как это исправить?

В интернете решения проблемы не нашел.
Если возможно, то, пожалуйста, дайте подробное описание параметров функции ShellExecute(). Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить блокнот `ShellExecute(0, "open", "notepad.exe", "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL)`. Где два нуля подряд, там предпалагаются строки, может в этом дело.

Comment: Для информации, код ошибки 0xC0000142 - это STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55). Вряд ли эта проблема связана с ShellExecute и вообще с вашим кодом, это похоже на проблему с Windows.

Comment: @AlexF Гигантское спасибо за решение проблемы. Помогла установка текущей директории.